# Default permissions for /opt directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, default

During the copying of certain program folders to my `/opt` directory I mistakenly changed the permissions of the `/opt` directory.

At the moment I (current user) can simply write/copy files to the `/opt` folder without appending sudo.

I need instructions to revert it back to the default as I've got some really important programs in that folder and Google Chrome has stopped working since that error occurred.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My permissions for **/opt** are `drwxr-xr-x` (with ownership `root:root`). That's the default.

You can set this ownership and permissions (regardless of how it's set currently) with:

```
sudo chown root:root /opt
sudo chmod 0755 /opt
```

If you changed the permissions of files and folders *inside* `/opt` as well, then a good solution might be more complicated. (You can add the output of `ls -lR /opt` to your question, to show this.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Permissions back to normal, though it did not seem to apply recursively.ie. to certain files within sub-folders of /opt directory.eg i had to reclaim certain google chrome files for root before it began  working again, even though i set the topmost /opt directory as belonging to root

Comment: I added mention of `chown -R` to change ownership recursively.